# How to create custom configs?

Tags: symfony

I checked symfony documentation

http://symfony.com/doc/master//components/config/definition.html

http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/resources.html

but I do see written:

can I add new configs to existing config files?

For example config_dev.yml I added to the bottom

```
AppBundle: aha
```

As I understood I need to define configuration rules in php files. Where? Is there some existing file where I have to add rules for config_dev.yml ? Maybe I have to create some class which extends some class?

I also created a file AppConfiguration.php

```
namespace AppBundle;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;

class AppConfiguration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /**
     * @return TreeBuilder
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('AppBundle');



        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

How the config will know that it has to check this file rules?

I tried to search some other hello world examples of symfony configuration but so far did not find.

Also if I create new config file - I guess I need to use this https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/resources.html

But currently I am more interested in adding additional values to existing files, because I only want few ones.

Answer (score 3):

This is explained in details in [Defining and Processing configuration values](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html).

This is a fairly large amount of work that should not be necessary for an AppBundle (only for shared bundles). You may consider using only a class named `AppConfig` (for instance) with constant or properties to define and use parameters.

As stated in the [symfony best practices](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#semantic-configuration-don-t-do-it):

> **Semantic Configuration: Don't Do It*
>
> As explained in How to Load Service Configuration inside a Bundle article, Symfony bundles have two choices on how to handle configuration: normal service configuration through the services.yml file and semantic configuration through a special *Extension class.
>
> Although semantic configuration is much more powerful and provides nice features such as configuration validation, the amount of work needed to define that configuration isn't worth it for bundles that aren't meant to be shared as third-party bundles.

--

But to answer your question, you need to create an [Extension class](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html), that will use a Processor to process your configuration.

Comment: Oh, you mean do not use .yml and other symfony stuff, just simple class without those treebuilters?

Comment: Yes, most application should not need such complex configuration (but there may be some exceptions), I've added some information from symfony best practices in my answer.

Comment: This practice had to be said at the beginning of http://symfony.com/doc/master//components/config/definition.html :) for new users it is confusing. And also choose bit more clear words, because "Don't define a semantic dependency injection configuration for your bundles." that I have read, but did not undrerstand from the meaning. Could write more simple - do not create configuration with treebuilder/validations which use .yml files when not sharing the bundle. Or smth like this.

Comment: What is best solution with environments? Now if I have just constants, its good, because I can access them everywhere without creating config class instance. But how others do when wanting dev and prod environments? Have to have getter methods and create instance or static class which checks environment and returns right config?

Answer (score 0):

In controllers at least its possible this way:

in config_dev.yml add this at the root:

```
parameters:
    test: aaa
```

In controller:

```
echo $this->container->getParameter('test');
```